# Close Vote from Question vs. from Review Queue

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

I've noticed that Close votes made from the Review Queue are counted in the individual cumulative totals of Close votes cast (seen by placing the cursor over the icon of a user on the Review Queue page), but Close votes made from a Question page are not.  Is this intentional?  If so, what is the thinking behind it?  Thanks.

Comment: what individual totals?

Comment: @Shog9  Thanks for your question, which I hope that I answered adequately in an edit to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those aren't close votes being counted - they're *reviews*.

The reviewer *may* have voted to close that many times, or they might've edited that many times or opted to Leave Open that many times - but most likely, that count reflects some combination of those actions.

There is currently no public counter for close votes.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  As a review count, it appears to be the sum over all the actions you listed.